# Composite component action attribute reutilization?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have a JSF 2.0 composite component as follows:

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="id"/>
  <composite:attribute name="action1" targets="#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.id}_1" requiered="true"/>
  <composite:attribute name="action2" targets="#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.id}_2" requiered="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:commandLink id="#{cc.attrs.id}_1" value="command link 1"/>
  <h:commandLink id="#{cc.attrs.id}_2" value="command link 2"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

as you can see for now I am using two different attributes named (action1, action2) and target them to the two commandLink's.

what I would like to do is: instead of having action1 & action2, I would like to have only one attribute named "action" and reuse this action for both commandLinks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a space separated list of client IDs in `targets` attribute. See also [the `<composite:attribute>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/attribute.html):

> If this element has a method-signature attribute, the value of the targets attribute must be interpreted as **a space** (not tab) **separated list of client ids** (relative to the top level component) of components within the `<composite:implementation>` section.